# How to get user details from keycloak (not logged in user but any user by his id)

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

In my Java web application with Spring Boot I have Keycloak authentication done but now I need to get user details of some user by id (not user that is logged in). Is it possible ? I want to get his roles, groups and data from Java code.

Comment: did you checkout the REST API? https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/10.0/rest-api/index.html

Comment: thanks, i will check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the REST API by getting an access token from:

@POST `${yourHost}/auth/realms/${yourRealm}/protocol/openid-connect/token`

with @RequestBody

```
{
  "client_id": "admin-cli",
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "secret",
  "grant_type": "password"
}
```

Then, call `${_HOST}/auth/admin/realms/${_REALM}/users`

using that token as a Header's parameter `"Authorization: bearer " + ${_TOKEN}`

Do the same to get userByID, but by calling: `${_HOST}/auth/admin/realms/${_REALM}/users/${_USER_ID}`